# Microsoft Signalr architecture and how it's working

Tags: node.js, websocket, signalr, real-time, signalr-2

I'm trying to understand how Signalr works. I have read a lot of documentation but I still don't get it completely.

I want to start by explaining my case. I have a react front application that communicate with a Nodejs Azure function.
I want to add realtime to it  by using Signalr.

In documentation I see that all tutorials are using ASP.NET to create Hubs on server side.

As I don't have any experiences in ASP.NET or C# I would like to know if there is a solution to use Signalr witout C# but NodeJS ( Javascript ) on server side ?

I would also know what is the difference between ASP.NET Core SignalR and ASP.NET SignalR ? ( [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is not clear enough for me)

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is part of the .NET framework. It should be used server side on ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core.

The difference between the two frameworks is that .NET is kinda the legacy Framework. .NET Core is a full rewrite that on the surface looks a like but is cross-platform, lighter and has best performances.

The goal of SignalR is to offer developers an easy library to use real time communication.
Depending on the server or client capacities, it will open a channel with the best protocol possible between them to realize real time operations.

NOW, what you need is a technology like SignalR (but not it) for NodeJS : https://socket.io/